# Parallel.ForEach with custom collection

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, .net-4.0, parallel.foreach

I am extending the `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` class to include an ID field, so I created a new custom `MailAddress` class that inherited from the existing class and a new custom `MailAddressCollection` class.  I then overrode the existing `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.To` to use my new collection.

I would like to process the recipients in parallel, but I can't get the syntax right.  This is the syntax I am using.

```
Parallel.ForEach(EmailMessage.To, (MailAddress address) =>
{
    emailService.InsertRecipient(emailId, address.DisplayName, address.Address, " ");
});
```

I get the following errors:

> The best overloaded method match for
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<EmailService.MailAddress>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EmailService.MailAddress>,
> System.Action<EmailService.MailAddress>)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'EmailService.MailAddressCollection'
> to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EmailService.MailAddress>'

What syntax do I need to use custom collections?

Here is the `EmailService.MailAddress` class:

```
public class MailAddress : System.Net.Mail.MailAddress
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains an identifier of the address for use in sending unique email links.
    /// </summary>
    public string ID = "";

    public MailAddress(string Address) : base(Address) 
    { 
     
    }

    public MailAddress(string Address, string Name): base(Address, Name)
    {

    }

    public MailAddress(string Address, string Name, string Id) : base(Address, Name)
    {
        ID = Id;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was complicating the issue.  I ended up using Parallel.For with a counter instead of ForEach.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, EmailMessage.To.Count, 
i => emailService.InsertRecipient(emailId, EmailMessage.To[i].DisplayName, 
EmailMessage.To[i].Address, EmailMessage.To[i].Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, we don't know what `EmailService.MailAddressCollection` actually implements. If it only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, you could try this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(EmailMessage.To.Cast<MailAddress>(), address =>
{
    emailService.InsertRecipient(emailId, address.DisplayName,
                                 address.Address, " ");
});
```

Comment: I added the mail address class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this. The SmtpClient class already has a [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) method.

Comment: This isn't the already made service.  This is a custom service to do additional features.